# showing that a flow $\phi(t;x_{0})$ goes to infinity.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Showing that a flow $\phi(t;x_{0})$ goes to infinity.

Hi there,

I'm having problems with the followin question:

Let $\phi(t;x_{0})$ be the flow of a differential equation $\dot{x}=p(x)$, with p(x) a polynomial of degree greater than 1. Assume that p(x)>0 for al x>a.

Show that $\phi(t;x_{0})$ goes to infinity in finite time for any $x_{0}>a$.

The main problem here is that if i try to solve this, i wil get an equation in the form:

$\int{\frac{1}{p(x)}} = t + C$. but integrating polynomials in the form $\frac{1}{x^k}$ with k>1 is kind of troublesome.....

Anyone got tips/hints for me?

Kees

Comment: You might have a look here: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.30.8149&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to solve the DE explicitely. It is enough to compare it to one that you can solve. Suppose $p(x)$ has degree $k>1$ and that $p(x)>0$ for $x\geq a$. Show there exists a $c>0$ such that $p(x)\geq c(x-a)^k$ for all $x\geq a$. Now solve $\dot x=c(x-a)^k$, showing that any solution $x(t)$ with $x(0)>a$ tends to infinity in finite time, and so same holds for the faster growing solutions of $\dot x=p(x).$